# How do I call a function "x" amount of times in python? Using a for loop?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, repeat, continuous

I have a cap.read() function where I am reading in frames from a video. The first call of the function is the zeroth frame, the second call is the 1st frame, etc... I am trying to call the function 1200 because I need to start my read-in at the 1200th frame.

Right now this is what I have, but I know it is incorrect.

Comment: Could you paste the code you are using right now?

Comment: `for _ in range(x): my_func();` Answers your question that is the "header".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer to your question was answered by @Shmack in the comments. The code is simply

```py
for i in range(1200):
    cap.read()
```

Given that your using the variable `cap`, I suspect that your using the OpenCV module. If that is the case, then you can simply set the frame you want to start at by using `cap.set(1, 1200)`

The `.set` function takes in its first parameter as the identifier, and for your case, you can simply leave that as `1`. The second parameter is the frame you wish to start at. You can read more about `cap.set()` [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)